# Instrumentation Testing WebView

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-webview

I wish to simply construct a custom `WebView` in my `InstrumentationTest` and then check if the correct initialisation has been done.

My custom `WebView`:

```
public class InteractiveWebView extends WebView
{
    public InteractiveWebView(final Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        initialise(context);
    }

    public InteractiveWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise(context);
    }

    public InteractiveWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialise(context);
    }

    private void initialise(final Context context)
    {
        if (!isInEditMode())
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            {
                setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            }
            else
            {
                setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }

            setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

            WebSettings settings = getSettings();

            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
            settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
            settings.setSupportZoom(false);
            settings.setUseWideViewPort(false);

            String databasePath = context.getApplicationContext().getDir("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath();
            settings.setDatabasePath(databasePath);
        }
    }
}
```

The `InstrumentationTest`:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class InteractiveWebViewTest
{
    @Test
    public void constructors()
    {
        Context baseContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();

        InteractiveWebView webView1 = new InteractiveWebView(baseContext);
        InteractiveWebView webView2 = new InteractiveWebView(baseContext, null);
        InteractiveWebView webView3 = new InteractiveWebView(baseContext, null, 1);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am at this point not asserting anything, *yet*.

The issue which I am facing is that when I call the first `WebView` constructor, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.os.MessageQueue android.os.Looper.mQueue' on a null object reference
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:229)
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:137)
at org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.setUiThread(ThreadUtils.java:39)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.ensureChromiumStartedLocked(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:197)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.startYourEngines(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:294)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:218)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:606)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:542)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:525)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:512)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:502)
at android.mobileconnect.gsma.com.library.view.InteractiveWebView.<init>(InteractiveWebView.java:17)
```

When I click on the `InteractiveWebView` link at line 17, it takes me to the constructor within that class and points to the `super(context);` call.

I have tried many other approaches such as extending the `InstrumentationTest` to be of type `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` in case it's the `Context` that's coming out to be null but I still get the same error. I've googled the issue several times but can't seem to fix the issue based on what I find.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by mocking the `InteractiveWebView` but ensuring it's being constructed within a Runnable running on the Main UI thread:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Given
        InteractiveWebView interactiveWebView = new InteractiveWebView(getActivity());
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```